# Is there a way to remove the even-odd rule of rounding for 5 and round up?

Tags: java, rounding

Making a application for ordering tickets. For the total, I added the subtotal, hst, and service fees together, and decimal formatted the sum for the total. If the total is x.85, it rounds down to x.8 but I want x.9
Is there a way to remove the even-odd rule for rounding 5 and round up?

I have tried BigDecimal but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.00");

grandTotal = subTotal + hst + serviceFees;
System.out.printf("%-40s%11s\n", "TOTAL:", df.format(grandTotal));
```

I expect the output to round up when there is a 5 to round, but it just rounds based on the even-odd rule.

Comment: Add 0.5 and round down?

Comment: round up whenever the number encounters a 5, instead of rounding based on the even-odd rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need only 1 fraction digit.**

You current code is rounding correctly, just too many fraction digits.

The rounding mode you are asking for is called **HALF UP**, which is a default for `DecimalFormat` and the only possible rounding mode for `printf()`.
(You can also use format `$#,###.#` if you don't want to display zeros as fraction.)

Therefore you can use your decimal format just fine or even `System.out.printf()` but limit **number of fraction digits** to **1**:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.0"); //set MIN and MAX fraction digits to 1
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);         //default but showing usage if needed

System.out.println(df.format(123454.84d));
System.out.println(df.format(123454.85d));
System.out.printf("$%,.1f", 123454.85d);          //HALF UP rounding the only option
```

prints:

```
$123,454.8
$123,454.9
$123,454.9
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using floating point (`double`), which is just an approximation of real values.
Especially with a list and a total, you will always have trouble to get everything right.
You have no control, whether the total is 2.35 (actually never) or 2.349999998, the latter which would round down.

Use BigDecimal with String constructors: `new BigDecimal("1.20")`, having a fraction of 2 decimals.

Mind you must use `add/multiply` i.o. +/*.

Answer (score 0):

Guys i just switched the double data type into a float type and it worked ayyyyy
!!!!!!!

Comment: In 50% the formating will work. Float actually worse than double.